# user.roles is not defined even though the user is defined and has a roles variable, discordjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

The user variable in my code is a discord user which has sub variables under it. I should be able to access user.roles but it says its undefined.

```
let iso = message.client.guilds.cache.get(`${config.serverID}`);
                let user = iso.members.fetch(args[1].slice(3, -1));
                return console.log(user.roles);
```

the console does give me info when i console.log the user.

```
joinedTimestamp: 1621628004254,
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessageChannelID: null,
    premiumSinceTimestamp: 0,
    deleted: false,
    nickname: 'test',
    _roles: [ '755571567861432411', '761262143647252511' ],
    user: User {
```

I left out some of the console log due to private info but I was wondering if anyone could help me access the user roles? I have used code just like it before and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, it helps to `await` fetching the user (make sure you're in an `async` function), so:

```
let user = await iso.members.fetch(args[1].slice(3, -1));
```

Then, the property you're looking for isn't just called `roles` but instead `_roles`, so you have to get the correct property.

Combined, your new code should look akin to:

```
let iso = message.client.guilds.cache.get(`${config.serverID}`);
let user = await iso.members.fetch(args[1].slice(3, -1));
return console.log(user._roles);
```

Comment: that did allow me to access the roles array but its not the correct one. is there a different way I need to grab the user because this wont let me user._roles.add because its not a valid function.

Comment: I was able to use `user.roles.add('role-id-here')` with no issue since `_roles` is just an array while `roles` is the Role Manager ([docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles)).  Are you getting any specific error message?

Comment: It just says that it can't execute the function add because user.roles does not exist. Im pretty sure all the needed packages are required at the start but is it possible that I'm missing one?